# how to close tabs of the IE one by one automatically using scripts which are opened since 2 mins using batch file, ...

Tags: javascript, batch-file

how to close tabs of the IE one by one automatically using scripts which are opened since 2 mins using batch file, ...

i have been using 
start " " "http://google.com/"
start " " "http://yahoo.com/"

it's a BATCH file script...

to open multiple urls in IE....

i want to close the tabs which are being opened since last 5 mins automatically using batch file or scripts.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not too familiar with the syntax but I can point you to the right direction. First you run a command to get all the current processes, and then you look for the one with title like..."google - Internet Explorer" , and then you execute end task (not end process!). Everything should be doable inside a batch script. For the 5 min part you can use task scheduler to do the trick